# How to convert localtime into YYYY-MM-DD with Perl

Tags: perl

I have this code which obtains the most recent coming friday, no matter what the current date is:

```
for(my $i = 1; $i < 8; $i++) {
     my $t = time() + $i * 24 * 3600;
     next unless (localtime($t))[6] == 5; # friday                                                                                               
     $nextfri = scalar(localtime($t));                                                                                                           
     last;                                                                                                                                        
}
```

This returns the date in the format: `Fri May 11 13:47:24 2018`

However, II must use this date for a SQL query, and so I must have this date in this format: `YYYY-MM-DD`

I have tried using Time::Piece:

```
 print STDERR "Time::Piece: " . Time::Piece->strptime("$nextfri", '%Y %m %d'), "\n";
```

But I receive this error: `Error parsing time at /usr/local/lib/perl/5.18.2/Time/Piece.pm line 481, <DATA> line 1.`

How do I change the format of the date?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code assumes every day has 24 hours, which is wrong. Fixed:

```
use Time::Local qw( timegm );

# This returns 4pm UTC if it's 4pm localtime.
# We do this because UTC doesn't have DST,
# so we can safely do date math.
my $time = timegm(localtime());

while (1) {
   $time += 24*60*60;
   last if ( gmtime($time) )[6] == 5;  # Sun=0, Fri=5
}
```

This can be optimized:

```
use Time::Local qw( timegm );

# This returns 4pm UTC if it's 4pm localtime.
# We do this because UTC doesn't have DST.
# so we can safely do date math.
my $time = timegm(localtime());

my $dow = ( gmtime($time) )[6];  # Sun = 0
my $days = ( 5 - $dow ) % 7;     # Days until Friday
$days += 7 if !$days;            # Days until next Friday
$time += $days * 24*60*60;
```

Now on to your question

```
use POSIX qw( strftime );

say strftime("%Y-%m-%d", gmtime($time));
```

---

You could use Time::Piece, which uses the same trick as above (internally).

```
use Time::Piece   qw( localtime );
use Time::Seconds qw( ONE_DAY );

my $tp = localtime;

my $dow = $tp->day_of_week;    # Sun = 0
my $days = ( 5 - $dow ) % 7;   # Days until Friday
$days += 7 if !$days;          # Days until next Friday
$time += $days * ONE_DAY;

say $tp->ymd;   # Or $tp->strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
```

---

Personally, I try to avoid Time::Piece. It's too easy to get things wrong (like you did).

```
use DateTime qw( );

my $dt = DateTime->now( time_zone => 'local' );

my $dow = $dt->day_of_week;    # Sun = 0
my $days = ( 5 - $dow ) % 7;   # Days until Friday
$days += 7 if !$days;          # Days until next Friday
$dt->add( days => $days );

say $dt->ymd;   # Or $dt->strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
```

Answer (score 5):

Use [`POSIX::strftime`](http://perldoc.perl.org/POSIX.html#FUNCTIONS) to convert localtime parts to a formatted string.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use POSIX qw{strftime};

my $nextfri;
for (my $i = 1; $i < 8; $i++) {
  my @t = localtime(time() + $i * 24 * 3600);
  next unless $t[6] == 5; # friday
  $nextfri = strftime '%Y %m %d', @t;
  last;
}
```

But I would suggest you use a library like [DateTime](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/DateTime) instead because the above code can lead to incorrect results because of its incorrect assumption that every day has 24 hours.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use DateTime;

my $nextfri = DateTime->now;
do {
  $nextfri->add(days => 1);
} until ($nextfri->day_of_week == 5);

print $nextfri->ymd(' '); # or '-'
```